My C# Blazor WebAssembly TelerikGrid Tooltip duplicating for all my rows
I have a grid that is populated with data from my Database using a DTO and a controller and I have the tooltip working but my issue is that it is the same tooltip for each row in my grid and I can't quite figure out what to do. Here is my grid code, I thought me doing the render would fix it but it doesnt. Any ideas at all would be appreciated.
<TelerikGrid class="NewPairsGrid" 
            Data="@Pairs" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"       
            RowHeight="15" 
            Height="1000px" 
            Pageable="true"
            PageSize="25"
            Sortable="true"
>
    <GridColumns>

        <GridColumn Field="PairCreatedTimeStamp" Title="Token Age" width="75px">
            <Template Context="dataItem">
                @if (dataItem is EthPairTradeInfoVDto ethPairTradeInfoVDto)
                {
                    var timestamp = CalculateElapsedTime(dataItem as EthPairTradeInfoVDto);
                    <span class="tooltip-target">@timestamp</span>
                    <TelerikTooltip TargetSelector=".tooltip-target" Width="auto" Height="auto" Position="@TooltipPosition.Right">
                    <Template Context="tooltipContext">
                        <span>
                            @RenderTooltipContent(ethPairTradeInfoVDto.PairCreatedTimeStamp)
                        </span>
                    </Template>
            </TelerikTooltip>                 
            </Template>
        </GridColumn>

RenderFragment RenderTooltipContent(DateTime? pairCreatedTimeStamp) => 
    builder =>
    {
        if (pairCreatedTimeStamp.HasValue)
        {
            builder.OpenElement(0, "span");
            builder.AddContent(1, $"Pair Timestamp: {pairCreatedTimeStamp.Value}");
            builder.CloseElement();
        }
    }; 


I have the same problem and I found that I use the same TargetSelector with the same class or id, I change with a unique Id or class like a TrailerPlate and its work
Here's my code :
    <GridColumn Title="Info" Width="30px" TextAlign="@ColumnTextAlign.Center" HeaderClass="center-me">
    <Template >
        @{
            <TelerikButton Id="@((context as LoadingOrder).TractorPlate)" Icon="@FontIcon.InfoCircle" ThemeColor="primary">
            </TelerikButton>
            <TelerikTooltip TargetSelector="@($"#{((context as LoadingOrder).TractorPlate)}")" ShowOn="@TooltipShowEvent.Click" Position="TooltipPosition.Bottom" Context="TelerikTooltip">
                <Template >
                    @{
                        var dataAttributes = context as LoadingOrder;
                        <div>
                                <b>Transporteur:</b> @dataAttributes?.CarrierName<br/>
                                <b>Client:</b> @dataAttributes?.CustomerName
                        </div>
                    }
                </Template>
            </TelerikTooltip>
        }
    </Template>
</GridColumn>

